# How to match text sequences that continue through child nodes (e.g. with sgml-style markup)?

Tags: xpath

```
<bits>
  <thing>Match this please</thing>
  <thing>Don't match this</thing>
  <thing>Match <b>this</b> please</thing>
</bits>
```

An expression like this:

```
//thing[text()='Match this please']
```

will locate the first 'thing' but not the third, because the phrase is distributed through a child node.

Is there an expression that would match the first *and* the third 'thing' in my example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
//thing[string()='Match this please']
```

jsfiddle:

- http://jsfiddle.net/ZG9n3/2/

Please check the reference to see if this is going to work for you:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#function-string

Answer (score 1):

> Is there an expression that would
>   match the first and the third 'thing'
>   in my example?

**You mean**: Is there an expression that would *select* the first and the third element named `thing`, based on their string value.

**Use**:

```
/*/thing[. = 'Match this please']
```

The predicate compares the *string value* of the context node to the string `"Match this please"`.

**By definition the [string value of an element](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/#element-nodes) is the concatenation (in document order) of all of its text-nodes descendents**.

**Note**: **Always try to avoid the `//` abbreviation** because its use may incur big inefficiency. Whenever the structure of an XML document is known, use a chain of specific location steps.